# Executing a query with a variable in a loop

Tags: oracle, query, select, plsql, cursors

I have two select, how can I do the same using a loop and a variable in PL SQL Developer.
I have:

```
select 1 as nm from dual;
select 2 as nm from dual;
```

I need something similar:

```
DECLARE x NUMBER;
BEGIN
 FOR X IN 1..2
  LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('SELECT ' || X || ' AS NM FROM DUAL;');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

In PL SQL Developer, each select is displayed in a separate tab:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to make the loop work so that the result is similar to the two select from the first example. The result in PL SQL Developer should be the same as in the screenshot

Comment: What output are you expecting? And what kind of output(dbms_output debug message, refcursor, PL/SQL Developer results grid that you can export to Excel etc)?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to join the result of two queries you can use `UNION ALL` clause:

```
select 1 as nm from dual
union all
select 2 as nm from dual;
```

It would be additional `DISTINCT` step using `UNION` without `ALL`. We don't need this in this case.

If you need to generate record set with subsequential records, good solution is  to "misuse" `CONNECT BY` clause:

```
select level nm from dual connect by level <= 2; -- Instead of 2 may be any number
```

But this structure is not efficient in large scale. Let say you have to generate 10 millions records. In this case the best solution is to use CARTESIAN JOIN on smaller subqueries:

```
select rownum rn
from
(select level rn from dual connect by level <= 1000) t1,
(select level rn from dual connect by level <= 1000) t2,
(select level rn from dual connect by level <= 10) t3;
```

Total rowcount will be multiplication the rowcounts of all subqeries: 1,000 * 1,000 * 10 = 10,000,000.

Comment: I apologize for the incomprehensible description. I need to use a loop to get the same results as the sequential execution of two "Select .. from". My code with a loop doesn't work.

Comment: It's still hard to me to understand your requirements. Maybe [table functions](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/when-is-a-function-like-a-table-when-its-a-table-function) are the solution to your problem?. Please try to explain the problem otherways.